# INotifyPropertyChanged and DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm making a test application to handle a CardReader, I have an enum with the states of the CardReader and a XAML window with a TextBlock, i want that when the state change the onPropertyChanged change the TextBlock with the name of the state.

Here is part of my code:

```
public class CardControler : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private CardState state;

    public CardState State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set
        {
            if (state != value)
            {
                state = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(state);
            }
        }
    }
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(CardState state)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(state.ToString()));
        }

    }
```

......................................................................

```
public partial class CardReader : Window
{

    public CardControler control { get; set; }

    public CardReader(int port)
    {

        this.DataContext = control;
        this.port = port;            
        InitializeComponent();
        ScreenWrite(CardState.Initializing);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(asincControlCreate));
        thread.Start();

    }
```

And in  the xaml

```
<TextBlock Name="Screen" Text="{Binding Path=control.state}></TextBlock>
```

I hope i explained my self correctly and somebody can help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: And what exactly is not working as expected?
I guess your Binding is off,
You normally are calling  OnPropertyChanged("PropertyName") to tell the framework that it needs to update all bindings on that property. Which means you need to fix your call of OnPropertyChanged and the Method on PropertyChanged as well.

Comment: What's the question?
Also, your Text attribute in the xaml is missing a closing double quote, but I assume that's just a typo here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are raising the `OnPropertyChanged` with the **value** that is changing, rather than the actual property name (i.e. "State" in this case).

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I suspect you also need to change your XAML to bind to the appropriate property (note, the property name is `State` not `state` - the XAML will be case sensitive):

```
<TextBlock Name="Screen" Text="{Binding Path=control.State}></TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following line is incorrect as you should pass `propertyName` as a parameter instead of `state.ToString()`:

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(state.ToString()));
```

So your code should look something like:

```
public CardState State
{
    get { return state; }
    set
    {
        if (state != value)
        {
            state = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("State");
        }
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In addition to this keep in mind that `xaml` is case sensitive so `{Binding State}` is not the same as `{Binding state}`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer at beggining it looks like it doesent work bu it do, I had to delete also this line : ScreenWrite(CardState.Initializing);

I dont understand whz but if i write something first in the screen it stays there and dont let the event change the textBlock

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the name of the property that changed, not its value:

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("State"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The case of the property in your binding needs to match the public property (`State`, not `state`):

`<TextBlock Name="Screen" Text="{Binding Path=control.State}></TextBlock>`

Answer (score 0):

You have alread set the datacontext of the page to `control` so your binding

```
<TextBlock Name="Screen" Text="{Binding Path=control.state}></TextBlock>
```

will be wrong.

your binding should be

```
<TextBlock Name="Screen" Text="{Binding Path=State}></TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
public CardControler control { get; set; }
```

try this:

```
public CardControler control = new CardControler();
```

Comment: I dont understand what have this related to my question sorry

Answer (score 0):

your OnPopertyChanged Event Call is wrong , you have to pass Property name as the argumeny. you can add the code i added below. that way you can avoid passing the parameter name altogether.

```
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
     {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
```